# The asset "ckeditor/init.js" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to implement ckeditor for active_admin. Getting this error : The asset "ckeditor/init.js" is not present in the asset pipeline. Any solutions will be very nice.

rails version : 5.2.3
ruby version : 2.6.2p47
active_admin version: 1.4.3

Answer (score 0):

`rake assets:precompile` solved my problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. But this didn't help me. Could you please write down all steps that you do to make it?

Comment: in your Gemfile.lock your ckeditor version must be ckeditor (4.3.0) you may check it. I set ckeditor version to 4.3.0 and problem solved for me. 
*gem 'ckeditor', '~> 4.3.0'*